# How to return column names based on cell value in Excel using multiple tables?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with two tables (like actual tables). One table lists App requirements and other shows Hardware requirements.

Example

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apps** | **Software Dev** | **Web Dev** | **Games Dev** |
| **2** | Word |  | x |  |
| **3** | Powerpoint |  | x |  |
| **4** | Excel | x |  | x |
| **5** | Outlook | x | x |  |

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **7** | **Hardware** | **Software Dev** | **Web Dev** | **Games Dev** |
| **8** | Laptop |  | x | x |
| **9** | Desktop | x | x | x |
| **10** | Mobile | x |  |  |

I have a cell where I input Job Title (e.g. Software Dev). I can't figure out VLOOKUPS to get my desired output of all the Apps and Hardware.

| Enter Job Title | Software Dev |
| --- | --- |
|  | Excel |
|  | Desktop |
|  | Mobile |

I would like the output to also have the side headers like "Apps" and "Hardware" but I would like to figure this one out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rethink how your data is laid out to make querying simpler.  The unique thing (unique id for the record, key for the row) would be the job title.  Everything else is based on the job title and would therefore be columns.  Instead of using "x" to designate whether or not a particular job should be assigned a particular piece of hardware or software use boolean logic "True" or a value of "1".

[image]

I also made the above a smart table (select all of the table cells, go to the "Insert" tab, select "Table", make sure "my table has headers" is checked).  I named it tblJobs under "Table Design" so that formulas would look cleaner.  For the lookup table I've limited user input using a data validation drop down list ("Data" tab -> "Data Validation") so that they can't type garbage in the field.  Otherwise they're going to type things wrong and complain about how it "doesn't work" when really they "can't type."

[image]

The formula below in O2 was copied down to the rest and is for whether or not the particular job should be assigned the specific hardware or Software:

- O2:  `=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("tblJobs[" & N2 & "]"), MATCH($O$1, tblJobs[Job Title], FALSE))=1, TRUE, FALSE)`

All of the formulas reference $O$1 so that when you select a different job from the drop down validation list all of the cells update based on the selected job.  Finally, if you wanted you could add a filter to columns N and O, and only show "True" values.

[image]

If you were going to keep the spreadsheet the same, I would create an ADDRESS() reference and then use INDIRECT() to return the contents of the address reference.

[image]

Where G2 = `=ADDRESS(MATCH(F2, A:A, FALSE), MATCH($G$1,A$1:D$1,FALSE))`
Then wrap in an indirect:  `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(F2, A:A, FALSE), MATCH($G$1,A$1:D$1,FALSE)))`

- Finds the row by searching down A:A using MATCH() for each thing you're looking for for each job.
- Finds the column by searching A1:D1 using MATCH() for each job you're referencing.
- Combine the row and column in an ADDRESS() function in the format ADDRESS(row, column) and it returns an address reference like $B$4.
- INDIRECT() then consumes the address reference and returns what exists in that location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, and yes I do 100% agree that we got the initial layout wrong which makes querying a little harder. However my real world example has around 1000+ rows on each end which makes switching layouts a little bit difficult. Also has more "sub tables" which means I cant combine them. Is a solution still possible for my original question? I came up with this which mightve been close? =IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("Table1[ " & B20 & "]", "Table2[ " & B20 & "]"), MATCH($G$1, Table1[#Headers], FALSE))=

Comment: Added a "if you can't rework the data" section.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly thank you so much!! Was easy to implement directly into my real  world solution too! Much appreciated

Comment: Why would you suggest `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...))` for the "if you can't rework the data" section? Just use `INDEX/MATCH`, it will be way faster. `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$5,MATCH(F2,$A$1:$A$5,0),MATCH($G$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)),INDEX($A$7:$D$10,MATCH(F2,$A$7:$A$10,0),MATCH($G$1,$A$7:$D$7,0)))`

Comment: Because the formula is more readable, and there would be no noticeable performance improvement between the two.  If you want prove that it will be "way faster" feel free though.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternate answer by using array formulas**

You may use array formulas for this purpose combined with some tricks to make it work, if you do not wish to alter original data and just work outside of it.

By using your example data (I changed the column on purpose for second table to demonstrate that they can be in different columns, or sheets). This was based on [this example](https://www.get-digital-help.com/index-match-multiple-results/#2)

[image]

| Character to spot requirements | Job Title | Column found in Table 1 | Column found in Table 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | Software Dev | =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(N4,A5:D5,0),4),1,"") | =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(N4,F5:I5,0)+5,4),1,"") |
|  | Columns for results | =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Apps",A5:D5,0),4),1,"") | =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Hardware",F5:I5,0)+5,4),1,"") |
|  | RowTableStarts | 3 | 3 |
|  | RowTableStarts | 10 | 10 |

Then on a separate row get the array formula as this one (one for apps and one for hardware)

In my image this is for apps

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("$"&$O$5&"$"&$O$6&":$"&$O$5&"$"&$O$7), SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDIRECT("$"&$O$4&"$"&$O$6&":$"&$O$4&"$"&$O$7), $M$4, 0)), MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT("$"&$O$4&"$"&$O$6&":$"&$O$4&"$"&$O$7)), ROW(INDIRECT("$"&$O$4&"$"&$O$6&":$"&$O$4&"$"&$O$7))), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1)))
```

And this is for hardware

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("$"&$P$5&"$"&$P$6&":$"&$P$5&"$"&$P$7), SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(INDIRECT("$"&$P$4&"$"&$P$6&":$"&$P$4&"$"&$P$7), $M$4, 0)), MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT("$"&$P$4&"$"&$P$6&":$"&$P$4&"$"&$P$7)), ROW(INDIRECT("$"&$P$4&"$"&$P$6&":$"&$P$4&"$"&$P$7))), ""), ROWS($A$1:A1)))
```

Extend the formula and get the results desired

Example working formulas

[image]

Although a VBA solution may be better if you really need to keep table formats (either build a dummy one that mixes them or loop through each one of them and append the results)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365, you can get this result by applying two `FILTER` functions and then joining both spill ranges (as described in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/kapi6r/joining_two_spill_ranges_to_a_single_spill_range/)). Combined into one formula, you get:

```
=LET(filter1,ROWS(FILTER(Apps[Apps],INDIRECT("Apps"&"["&Selection&"]")="x")),filter2,ROWS(FILTER(Hardware[Hardware],INDIRECT("Hardware"&"["&Selection&"]")="x")),seq,SEQUENCE(filter1+filter2),IF(seq<=filter1,INDEX(FILTER(Apps[Apps],INDIRECT("Apps"&"["&Selection&"]")="x"),seq),INDEX(FILTER(Hardware[Hardware],INDIRECT("Hardware"&"["&Selection&"]")="x"),seq-filter1)))
```

In this formula, the first table is called `Apps`, the second `Hardware`. `Selection` is the named range for the cell where I made a dropdown with your three options.

To get the linked "category" in adjacent cells, I've simply used `INDEX/MATCH`. I've entered above-mentioned formula in `H3`, so:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(MATCH(H3,Apps[Apps],0)>0,"Apps"),IF(MATCH(H3,Hardware[Hardware],0)>0,"Hardware")),"")
```

This one you should drag down to the max of your spilled results (or beyond that, since the outer `IFERROR` gets you `BLANK` in case of no result).

Result:

[image]